# How can I check efficiently check variables for a particular value in R and flag rows containing it?

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr

I want to create a variable that flags whether one or more of multiple variables has a particular value.

```
week  Mon  Tues  Weds  Thurs  Fri  Sat
1     jon  jon   jon   jon    mary mary
2     jane jane  jane  jane   jane jane
3     mary mary  mary  mary   mary jane
```

I want to create a binary variable that flags for each week whether Mon, Weds, or Sat of that week == "jon" or "mary" Is there a way to do this without creating a long ifelse statement that checks each variable individually?

```
week  Mon  Tues  Weds  Thurs  Fri  Sat  flag
1     jon  jon   jon   jon    mary mary 1
2     jane jane  jane  jane   jane jane 0
3     mary mary  mary  mary   mary jane 1
```

I tried

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(flag = +any(c_across(Mon, Weds, Sat)
  %in% ("jon", "mary")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

but I get an error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `flag`.
x unused arguments (Mon, Weds, Sat)
i Input `flag` is `+...`.
i The error occurred in row 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(flag = colSums(apply(cbind(Mon, Weds, Sat), 1, `%in%`, c("jon", "mary"))) > 0)
#   week  Mon Tues Weds Thurs  Fri  Sat  flag
# 1    1  jon  jon  jon   jon mary mary  TRUE
# 2    2 jane jane jane  jane jane jane FALSE
# 3    3 mary mary mary  mary mary jane  TRUE
```

I think the problem with `across` is that it's trying to do something to *each* column, not a summary of sorts of all of them. Let's try `purrr::pmap` insteadL

```r
library(purrr)
df %>%
  mutate(flag = pmap(list(Mon, Weds, Sat),
                     ~ +any(unlist(...) %in% c("jon", "mary"))))
#   week  Mon Tues Weds Thurs  Fri  Sat flag
# 1    1  jon  jon  jon   jon mary mary    1
# 2    2 jane jane jane  jane jane jane    0
# 3    3 mary mary mary  mary mary jane    1
```

A third (using your request for `c_across`):

```r
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(flag = +any(c_across(c(Mon, Weds, Sat)) %in% c("jon", "mary"))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 8
#    week Mon   Tues  Weds  Thurs Fri   Sat    flag
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1     1 jon   jon   jon   jon   mary  mary      1
# 2     2 jane  jane  jane  jane  jane  jane      0
# 3     3 mary  mary  mary  mary  mary  jane      1
```

Comment: I'm confused how this would only check the Mon, Weds, and Sat variables and not all of them

Comment: I'm not getting an error anymore, but flag=1 for some observations where flag should =0. Seems like it's still checking all the variables?

Comment: These are either throwing errors or still searching across all columns, but I guess there's something weird going on with my data

Comment: I can't help if you don't explain what kind of errors you're getting. If this doesn't work with your data, then it suggests that your sample data in the question is not representative. Perhaps you could update your sample data so that this code triggers the error?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `rowwise` or looping over the rows, we can make it more efficient if we loop over the columns with `map` and `reduce` it

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(flag = map(select(., Mon, Weds, Sat), `%in%`, c("jon", "mary")) %>%
          reduce(`|`) %>% `+`)
#  week  Mon Tues Weds Thurs  Fri  Sat flag
#1    1  jon  jon  jon   jon mary mary    1
#2    2 jane jane jane  jane jane jane    0
#3    3 mary mary mary  mary mary jane    1
```

---

A corresponding option in `base R` is `lapply/Reduce`

```
df$flag <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[c('Mon', 'Weds', 'Sat')],
          `%in%`, c("jon", "mary"))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(week = 1:3, Mon = c("jon", "jane", "mary"), Tues = c("jon", 
"jane", "mary"), Weds = c("jon", "jane", "mary"), Thurs = c("jon", 
"jane", "mary"), Fri = c("mary", "jane", "mary"), Sat = c("mary", 
"jane", "jane")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option using `rowSums` + `Reduce`

```
df$flag <- +(rowSums(
  Reduce(
    `+`,
    lapply(
      c("jon", "mary"),
      `==`,
      df[c("Mon", "Weds", "Sat")]
    )
  )
) > 0)
```

such that

```
  week  Mon Tues Weds Thurs  Fri  Sat flag
1    1  jon  jon  jon   jon mary mary    1
2    2 jane jane jane  jane jane jane    0
3    3 mary mary mary  mary mary jane    1
```